# Confusing grammatical construction with 'versammeln' involving datives

Tags: translation, dative

I found this sentence [here](https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/buecher/autoren/drei-buecher-zum-80-geburtstag-des-schriftstellers-uwe-timm-16699858.html):

> Unbegabter zum Zynismus kann man kaum sein, menschenfreundlicher wohl
>   auch nicht: Zum achtzigsten Geburtstag des Schriftstellers Uwe Timm
>   versammelt ein Band Essays, einer Würdigungen und einer Texte zum
>   Werk.

The question is about the second fragment. I can guess the meaning: a volume of essays, some appreciation, and texts of his work are being collected on his 80th birthday. What I don't get is the 'einer' before 'Würdigungen' and 'Texte'.

- First of all, why dative here but not before 'Band'.
- Why dative at all? Does 'versammeln' require dative?
- Why 'einer' before plurals like 'Würdigungen' and 'Texte'?

The construction doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Einer* is not dative. It is nominative and stands for *ein Band*.

The sentence could alternatively be written as

> Zum achtzigsten Geburtstag des Schriftstellers Uwe Timm versammelt ein Band Essays, ein Band Würdigungen und ein Band Texte zum Werk.

An example sentence to illustrate this usage of *einer*:

> Ich habe zwei Bälle. Einer ist weiß und der andere schwarz.

Comment: Thanks. How would you translate the 'zum Werk' bit?

Comment: @ToGa, here, *Werk* refers to his opus or literary oeuvre.

Comment: @ToGa  *Texte zum Werk* means secondary literature.